# How to increase the font size of labels on pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart

I am so sorry for my basic question. I want to increase the font size of labels. I tried `cex.label` . But it doesn't work.

```
pie(c(3632,20,491,991,120))
```

Comment: I think it's `cex.lab`. Not `cex.label`.

Comment: Its good practice to make your examples as small as possible while still working (minimal example). This makes answering your question less work because its easier to fokus on what is the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Solution

Using option `cex` should do the job.

```
pie(c(3632,20,491,991,120), cex=5)
```

[image]

## PS: [#piechartsareevil](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23piechartsareevil&src=typd)